# Securing HTML LocalStorage

Tags: html, angular, encryption, local-storage, angular-local-storage

I'm currently developing an app in Angular with a laravel backend. I would usually store the user data as a JSON in LocalStorage. This new app deals with secure information so it can't be stored in plaintext.

The database is encrypted and traffic uses SSL but locally, I want to encrypt the data locally and store it so a user doesn't need to log in everytime they open the app.

My current workflow is the user logs in, the user is verified and the user data retrieved from the server. 
The data is saved as a service in Angular and stored as a CryptoJS.AES encrypted JSON string with the users password as a passphrase. 
Then in the next loading of the app, the app checks if there's any data in LocalStorage and if there is, the user only needs to enter their password and CryptoJS.AES decrypt will decrypt the json and store as a service variable again.

Is there any flaw or vulnerability or better library available for this kind of idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modern standard for this kind of authentication are [Json Web Tokens, JWT](https://jwt.io/introduction/). They are perfect for angular and other SPAs, easy to implement and secure.

Comment: I use JWT from Laravel to authenticate actions currently. My reason for LocalStorage is to also store other information for that user including any keys for other APIs such as Stripe Connect, I could eliminate these from storage and only keep the JWT

Comment: The token can hold whatever data you want, true. @Musa You'll still safe it to localstorage

Comment: I've previously only used JWT to authenticate users actions, I haven't actually used it to store data so I might look into this instead, thanks for the idea

Comment: I've looked at passport which is what I'm currently using and there's no option to store extra data in the JWT payload so I still need a secure store method for LocalStorage https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/94

Comment: Use a library that fully supports JWT instead, or implement it your own, it's very easy

Comment: I'd rather not have to implement a whole other library. Also, https://jwt.io also recommends not saving the JWT in plaintext as it could be a security risk

Answer (score 0):

One way to look at this is that the users' computers are protected by login/password already. The local storage can be accessed only either by your site or by the users through the developer console. Thus, you do not really gain anything by encrypting the local storage.

Actually, by storing password hashes locally you introduce a potential attack vector.

Comment: I'm using angular with Cordova currently to build a smartphone app so it would be more accessible to people. Given LocalStorage also stores in plaintext I'd like to protect against any other apps or root attacks probing for information. Mainly just third party API keys like Stripe Connect user keys that could use some extra protection on my end.

Answer (score 0):

Check out  [SecurityJS.128](https://github.com/Parking-Master/SecurityJS.128). It is a JavaScript client-side library you can hide `sessionStorage` and `localStorage`. You can use the `window` [`secureStorage`](https://github.com/Parking-Master/SecurityJS.128#windowsecurestorage-api) API